# Why is Railo in conjunction with IIS performing slowly?

Tags: iis-7, railo, cfml

I have ColdFusion installed in my machine.

1. Just now I have downloaded and installed **Railo**.
2. I have **stopped** the ColdFusion application server.
3. I have created a simple app and mapped with **IIS**.
4. Railo is taking huge amount of time to run a single .cfm file.

So can anyone please suggest how **Railo With IIS** should be configured so that it will run faster?

It works fine with Tomcat, but I want to use it with IIS.

Comment: Did you restart the ColdFusion application server?  It has to be running in order to process the `.cfm` files.  Did you [follow the instructions here](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/wiki/Installation:InstallerDocumentation:MSAddingSites)?

Comment: Yes i have done exactly in the same way.
1 . If ColdFusion Application Server is running, then all the .cfm files are processed by ColdFusion,not by Railo.
2. If I stop the CF Application Server, then the .cfm files are processed by Railo,But the processing is quite slow. So i want a solution for this.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I did not realize that you also have Adobe ColdFusion installed on the machine. Did you create a new website for the Railo code? Does that site still have the Adobe Handler Mappings for ColdFusion files?

Comment: Could you please explain me where I can find the "Adobe Handler Mappings for ColdFusion files". I think it is present inside "Handlers Mapping" under "Server Components" of IIS,where different handlers are present for .cfm/.cfc files.

Comment: Yes. I will post an answer as it provides more space.

Answer (score 1):

IIS is trying to connect to ColdFusion before Railo
, but as you've stopped the CF service it's just waiting for the timeout.

You should remove/disable the ColdFusion connector.

Comment: Can you please explain "How to remove/disable" ColdFusion connector?

Answer (score 1):

The Handler Mappings can be defined at different levels in IIS; server level or website(s) level. If they are defined at the server level then each website will inherit those properties and chances are your Railo website has them too.

If they are defined at the server level you should be able to remove them under your Railo's website level without affecting any other sites.  But be careful to remove the correct one(s) because Railo needs to have mappings for it to work as well.  [See this page for what it should look like for Railo with IIS](http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2010/9/16/railo-on-iis-7).

For the existing Handler Mappings tied to your Adobe install, click on the website for your Railo install. Double-click the Handler Mappings icon. The Adobe install creates four mappings.

1. cfcHandler - path is *.cfc
2. cfmHandler - path is *.cfm
3. cfmlHandler - path is *.cfml
4. JWildCardHandler - path is *

The Adobe ISAPI DLL assigned for the first three handlers is something like `C:\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll` (depending on your install). For the JWildCardHandler handler the executable is something like `C:\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll`.  Check to see how yours are assigned.   The Railo installation may have overwritten some or all of these.

According to the page that I linked above Railo only creates handlers for `*.cfm` and `*.cfc` and they should point to the Railo ISAPI DLL. You should remove any of the Adobe handlers that still exist under your Railo website.  I am guessing that the JWildCardHandler is the culprit here and it is trying to pass your requests to the Adobe install.

NOTE: If you remove the handlers in this way, under the Railo website, the changes will be written to the `web.config` file in the root of your Railo website. If you make a backup of this file before making changes then you can always revert back to what you had.

Answer (score 0):

- Go into the web site properties, handlers
- select coldfusion handler
- delete it

Comment: Are you referring to "Handlers Mapping" under "Server Components" of IIS ?

Comment: Do I need to remove handlers for "*.cfm,*.cfml,*.cfc" etc.Am I correct? OR something else you are pointing to.

Comment: In IIS, simply select the Website you want to edit, then select HANDLERS in the right pane.
You only need to remove the COLDFUSION handlers, DO not remove the Railo ones, or Railo will of course not work either.

Comment: I have removed all the handlers for ColdFusion,But still railo is very slow,please suggest what shall i do,I am using(ColdFusion9,IIS7,Railo 4.0)

Comment: check the  tomcat logs, I have noticed on several installs that tomcat keeps re-creating all the default tomcat apps over and over which slows down Railo.

Comment: That slows down Tomcat's startup, but shouldn't affect request time for an individual CFM file (assuming "still railo is very slow" is describing the same issue as implied in the question; needs clarification of exactly what is slow).

Comment: peter if it were only happenning during startup then that would we true, but it doesnt, it  happens continuously thus affecting tomcats performance continually. I have seen this on 3 installs so far. I suspect others have it too but have simply never noticed as  haven't looked at tomcat logs

Comment: Oh, so even when the default apps are already there it overwrites them again? :/ Never noticed it myself, but then I mostly work with Jetty.